# Link "This Edit" text to "Suggested Edit" Link

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, suggested-edits

I have noticed something like when I suggest edit. then always it shows this message

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

and for status I have to go to `profile -> activity ->  suggestions -> suggested edit`

lots of steps...

It is not possible like just add link of suggested edit on `This edit` text like...

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>
> [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1790064) will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

Comment: it is not same and there is no answer on that given link

Comment: It's the same thing, except you're not suggesting the same piece of text to be linked - that's relatively minor, as long as the suggested edit is linked somewhere in there. There's no answer indeed, because it's neither implemented nor declined (yet).

Comment: @Mat beat me too that about the fact that it is a duplicate, and also, the rules for duplicates requiring an answer on MSO is a little more relaxed.  You are asking for the exact same feature, and having multiple feature requests for the same feature is pointless.  Just upvote that feature request or add a bounty to it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 and Mat I don't know about that question. but hope this feature request apply in nearest future.