# Add a link to review section while quoting "Thanks for your edit!" in posts

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, privileges

> **OK, the title is pretty bad!**

When users who have not yet earned/achieved the "[Edit questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)" privileges, try to submit an edit, they are shown the following message:

> **Thanks for your edit!** 
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

I request that since Stack Overflow can track those reviews for each question for the user who edited the message, make the review page for this edit appear in this message as well. Currently, we're forced to got to *User > Activity > Suggestions* to find the suggested edit.

[image: Preview mode]

Thus, the message will instead become:

> **Thanks for your edit!** 
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14204).

And on clicking upon the link, I will be easily directed to that specific suggested edit review.

[image: Review Page]

Comment: +1 was thinking of adding a feature request for this. While many of us know where to find the link, many don't and may never see why their edits are rejected.

Comment: @ben OK, I see what you meant by that =) Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173786/link-this-edit-text-to-suggested-edit-link